# How can I solve this error [missing 1 required positional argument: 'request']?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When I tried using a session on DetailView class in the Django project, I have an error and it does not work because of the missing a request object.

in that case, how should I do?

Would you mind telling me how should I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

---

**the error code**

```
TypeError at /detail/41/
check_session() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

---

**views.py**

```
class DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):  
  model = sampleDB
  template_name = 'detail.html'

  def check_session(self, request):
      if not 'history' in request.session:
          request.session['history'] = {'user': self.request.user, 'id': self.kwargs['pk']}

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      self.check_session()
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      return context
```

---

**project/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
]
```

**app/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.WelcomeView.as_view(), name='welcome'),
    path('home/', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('detail_edit/<int:pk>/', views.DetailEditView.as_view(), name='detail_edit'),
    path('resister_history/', views.ResisterHistoryView.as_view(), name='resister_history'),
    path('resister_vegetable/', views.ResisterVegetableView.as_view(), name='resister_vegetable'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.DeleteView.as_view(), name='delete'),
    path('inquiry_login/', views.InquiryLoginView.as_view(), name='inquiry_login'),
    path('inquiry/', views.InquiryView.as_view(), name='inquiry'),

    path('404/', views.Error404View.as_view(), name='404'),
    path('403/', views.Error403View.as_view(), name='403'),
    path('500/', views.Error500View.as_view(), name='500'),

]
```

---

**Development environment**

- Python: 3.7.5
- Django: 2.2.2

Comment: When you call `self.check_session()` you aren't passing any arguments, though it expects one. What are you supposed to give it?

Comment: self.check_session(self.request) or rework your function that it doesn't take request argument as it is available through self

Comment: @C.Nivs, I want to pass a request to check_session, but I don't know how can I pass it.

Comment: @ iklinac, when I try to do with self.check_session(self.request), I had this error [ Object of type CustomUser is not JSON serializable ]

Comment: @tio Please show ur URL patterns. probably, The error is on there.

Comment: @Shantanu Nath, I added them in the question!

Comment: i think u don't need to pass "request" instead u can use **kwargs. For session you can find it through self.request.session.

Comment: @Shantanu Nath, do you mean I can write the code as this [ def check_session(self, **kwargs):]? in this case, it also makes an error.

Answer (score 1):

`check_session() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

At some point you call the method `check_session()`. The method `check_session()` is defined like this:

`def check_session(self, request):`

This means you instructed the method to expect you to call it like this:
`check_session(request=some_value)` instead of `check_session(some_value)`

It is possible to pass it like `check_session(some_value)` but then you'd have to iterate through `kwargs` to find what you are looking for. But less readable and more work.

---

**After morning coffee:**

In views.py you call `self.check_session()` from `get_context_data`. The `check_session` expects something to be passed to it. You do not pass anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed the code as self.check_session(request=self.request) instead of self.check_session(self.request), but I still have an error code like this [TypeError at /detail/41/
Object of type CustomUser is not JSON serializable]

Comment: Wut? `def check_session(self, request)` can be called both as `check_session(request=some_value)` *or* `check_session(some_value)`. That function signature forces neither named arguments nor positional arguments.

Comment: @tio That is not the same issue.

Comment: @deceze You are right. I should not say stuff before coffee

Comment: I tried to call self.check_session() from get_context_data but I still have the error code like this.[ TypeError at /detail/41/
check_session() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
 ]